# Keep timestamp when copying my SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, database, timestamp

I'm copying an SQL Server 2005 database from one server to another, with the Database>Tasks>Copy Database wizard, and it works great, except for the timestamp column whose values are not copied.

Is there a way to have the timestamp values be preserved on database copy?

Comment: I think that the  [SQL Server] mark in the title is superfluous. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it possible for you to use a backup and then restore it to the server instead? Could be more trouble than it's worth in some cases, but it worked for me more than one time.

Answer (score 1):

Database backup restore is likely to work, but the best method I've used is SQL Data Compare:
http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Compare/index.htm

Makes patching data and schema changes (via the SQL Compare product) so easy...