# How do I preserve timestamp values when altering a table in SQL Server (T-SQL)?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql, timestamp

Or: how to copy timestamp data from one table to another?

Using SQL Server 2008 and having old design documents which requires a table to has the columns ordered in a certain way (with `timestamp` column last, something I guess comes from the time when Excel was used instead of an SQL database) I need to add a column in the middle of a table, keeping the `timestamp` data intact...

Do you know how to instruct SQL Server to do this?

Example T-SQL code:

```
-- In the beginning...
CREATE TABLE TestTableA
(
    [TestTableAId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TestTableAText] varchar(max) NOT NULL,
    [TestTableATimeStamp] [timestamp] NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO TestTableA (TestTableAText) VALUES ('TEST')
```

-- Many years pass...

-- Now we need to add a column to this table, but preserve all data, including timestamp data. 
-- Additional requirement: We want SQL Server to keep the TimeStamp last of the column.

```
CREATE TABLE TestTableB
(
    [TestTableBId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TestTableBText] varchar(max) NOT NULL,
    [TestTableBInt] [int] NULL,
    [TestTableBTimeStamp] [timestamp] NOT NULL
)

-- How do we copy the timestamp data from TestTableATimestamp to `TestTableBTimestamp`?

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [TestTableB] ON

-- Next line will produce errormessage:
-- Cannot insert an explicit value into a timestamp column. Use INSERT with a column list to exclude the timestamp column, or insert a DEFAULT into the timestamp column.

INSERT INTO [TestTableB] (TestTableBId, TestTableBText, TestTableBTimeStamp) 
    SELECT TestTableAId, TestTableAText, TestTableATimestamp 
    FROM TestTableA

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [TestTableB] OFF

GO
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Somewhat related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785305/keep-timestamp-when-copying-my-sql-server-database?rq=1 but it has not been answered in a way that helps this issue...

Comment: a view may be a viable solution? this way you could put the fields in any order with no change to the actual table.

Comment: the word "timestamp" is ungainly in SQL Server as it has absolutely nothing to do with time. If your column has the data type of "timestamp" then look hard at Ben's answer. i do hope "timestamp" hasn't been used as a column heading, that would not be great. see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/84ea9/1 - oh sorry i missed the DDL which specifies the column as data type timestamp - sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop table TestTableB first and then run a query:

```
SELECT 
    TestTableAId AS TestTableBId, 
    TestTableAText AS TestTableBText, 
    cast(null as int) as TestTableBInt,
    TestTableATimestamp AS TestTableBTimeStamp
INTO TestTableB
FROM TestTableA
```

Comment: You need to specify the type of the new column: `cast(null as int) as TesteTableBInt` will do it

Comment: Many thanks! Just love how fast you can get answers here that Google seem unable to answer at all.

Comment: Could not upvote back when I did recieve this answer. At least now I could return the favor and upvote. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

First check requirements: It depends if you need to preserve the timestamps. You actually may not, since they are just `ROWVERSION` values and don't actually encode the time in any way. So check that.

Why you might not want to preserve them: The only purpose of `TIMESTAMP` or `ROWVERSION` is to determine if the row has changed since last being read. If you are adding a column, you may *want* this to be seen as a change, particularly if the default is non-null.

If you DO need to preserve the timestamps see Dmitry's answer.